# Pinescript: Not able to execute arrays with function

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to code a script, where it takes a input date, then adds numbers from an array to that date and plots the background with the resultant date for all the array items. However getting error like "cannot call operator"
Seeking help pls.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
starttime1   = input.time(timestamp("01 Nov 2021 00:00"), "Start Time") 
starttime2   = input.time(timestamp("01 Nov 2021 00:00"), "Start Time2")
event_days1  = array.from(27,39,47,55,61,77,82,99,109,125,137,159,164,191,203,219,246,258,273,301,328,354)
post_days   = input.int(5)

fDays(src) =>
    pre_ts = starttime1 - 86400000
    post_start_ts = starttime1 + 86400000 * src
    post_end_ts = starttime1 + 86400000 * (src + post_days)
    pre_range = time >= pre_ts and time < starttime1
    post_range = time >= post_start_ts and time < post_end_ts
    pre_range

pre_range1 = fDays(event_days1)
bgcolor(pre_range1 ? #0000FF : na)
```

Comment: The code you shared throws `line 16: Undeclared identifier 'src'` error. If I add `src=close` somewhere, it compiles fine and I can add it to the chart.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I want to use the values of the array to calculate and plot. I tried changing pre_range1= fDays(event_days1) to get each value, calculate and plot, but its shows an error " Cannot call operator *...)
Can you guide pls? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

event_days1 is supposed to be an integer array, right? Try to be more explicit in declaring variables and get used to **var/varip** prefix, see pine reference link below.

```
varip int[] event_days1 = array.from(1,2,..,n)
```

Or with input.string to easily confirm/change values. This sets values in *event_days1_stringarray* first then use *event_days1_integerarray* in your script.

```
//string input for n comma separated values.
//to be converted in first bar only to avoid infinite loop
varip string[]  event_days1_stringarray = str.split( input.string( "20,21,22", confirm = true ), "," )
varip           event_days1_integerarray = array.new_int( ) //empty int[]
if barstate.isfirst
    for event_days1_singlestringvalue in event_days1_stringarray
        array.push( event_days1_integerarray, int( str.tonumber( event_days1_singlestringvalue ) ) )
    array.sort( event_days1_integerarray ) //optionally
plot( array.size( event_days1_integerarray ) )
```

Use numeric and comma characters only in this input field no *space* nor **"**.

Does it run as expected?

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Variable_declarations.html#declaration-modes